# How do I make wxListCtrl use the native macos implementation?

Tags: macos, wxwidgets, wxpython

I am trying to have my `wxListCtrl` use the native implementation on macos, but I'm only getting the generic implementation.

According to the [wxWiki](https://wiki.wxwidgets.org/WxListCtrl):

> Starting with wxWidgets 2.8 (wxMac), wxListCtrl uses a native implementation for report mode, and uses a generic implementation for other modes.

I have already set my `wxListCtrl` to `LC_REPORT`, but I still get the generic implementation.

What am I doing wrong?

(I'm using Python 3.8.2 on macOS 10.15.4 Catalina, and tested with both stable wxPython 4.0.7 and the latest snapshot build `wxPython-4.1.0a1.dev4650+de25f309-cp38-cp38-macosx_10_9_x86_64.whl`)

---

Minimal example

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import wx

class MyForm(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, wx.ID_ANY, 'Example')

        panel = wx.Panel(self, wx.ID_ANY)
        self.index = 0

        self.list_ctrl = wx.ListCtrl(panel, style=wx.LC_REPORT)
        self.list_ctrl.InsertColumn(0, 'Title')

        btn = wx.Button(panel, label='Add row')
        btn.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.add_line)

        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        sizer.Add(self.list_ctrl, 0, wx.ALL|wx.EXPAND, 5)
        sizer.Add(btn, 0, wx.ALL|wx.CENTER, 5)
        panel.SetSizer(sizer)

    def add_line(self, event):
        line = "Row %s" % self.index
        self.list_ctrl.InsertItem(self.index, line)
        self.index += 1


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = wx.App()
    frame = MyForm()
    frame.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The native `wxListCtrl` implementation under Mac turned out to be too problematic and so was dropped in wx 3. If you can, consider using `wxDataViewCtrl` which is native under Mac and generally usable, even if it still has some limitations compared to the generic version due to native API peculiarities.